# How can I use FitBit API for website development?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, fitbit

I am trying to use the FitBit API at website development, I want to make a website from scratch but I'm unable to do so.

I've followed the steps described [here](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+API) and I have created a VB.NET Website in Visual Studio based on the ideas described [here](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API+.NET+Client). I have downloaded the OauthNET-Release library, referenced the DLLs into my project and my web.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<!--<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>-->

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="foo" type="bar"/>
    <!-- lines omitted -->
  </configSections>
  <oauth.net.components>
    <!-- Components -->
    <components>
      <!-- Signing provider for HMAC-SHA1 -->
      <component service="OAuth.Net.Common.ISigningProvider, OAuth.Net.Common" lifestyle="thread"/>
      <!-- Nonce provider -->
      <component service="OAuth.Net.Common.INonceProvider, OAuth.Net.Common"/>
      <!-- State store -->
      <component service="OAuth.Net.Consumer.IRequestStateStore, OAuth.Net.Consumer"/>
    </components>
  </oauth.net.components>
  <!-- lines omitted -->
</configuration>
```

I've tried to build the website, but it wasn't successful and I received this message:

```
Error   11  Unrecognized configuration section oauth.net.components.
```

My question is: What should I do to make this work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you add the section registration to webconfig's `<configSections>`? Like this:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="oauth.net.components" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor"/>
  <!-- other stuff -->
</configSections>
```